# C# How to join tables from one mdb to another mdb?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I would like to add data from one mdb file into other mdb file without duplicates. Both files have the same tables and colums.

I thought I could make oledbconnection to multiple mdb files and then use SQL to do that, but it seems that you can't connect to many databases at once.

Is there simpler solution than opening the first database, read data from it to array for example, and then open the second one and add data to it?

Comment: What about linking tables from one db to the other db?

Comment: @Steve The target database is used by other program and I don't have a code for that program and I don't know how exacly the program uses the files. So I'm not sure if it will work in my case.
Is it possible to link two db in C#?